# Jessie Lite Pi 3 inbuilt Wi-Fi won't work

Tags: pi-3, wifi, jessie-lite

I downloaded the latest version of Jessie Lite (2017-04-10) and followed the [setup guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md). Wi-fi won't work.

Here is my problem as near as I can figure it out. Wi-Fi details in Jessie are entered into `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` The file originally looks something like this:

```
country=AU
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

Then, when the AP details are input, it looks like this:

```
country=AU
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network{
ssid="your ssid"
psk="your pwd"
}
```

The really important line in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` is:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
```

Which directs control to the file `wpa-supplicant` in `/var/run`. My problem is that this file and `wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid`, are both present on a fresh Jessie Lite SD card but mysteriously missing when I reboot after entering my routers details.

I can't fathom why entering Wi-Fi details into `etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` causes files necessary for the Wi-Fi  to work to be removed from `/var/run`?

Comment: In the meantime Jessie is deprecated and out of support. Have you tried it with up to date Raspbian Buster now?

Answer (score 0):

My wpa_supplicant.conf file is similar to yours, it contains the line 
`ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev` and the file /var/run/wpa_supplicant is missing. However, the wifi connects fine.

I use the commands below to connect, you can give it a try

```
ifdown wlan0
nano /etc/network/interfaces
    allow-hotplug wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-config /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant
systemctl restart networking
systemctl daemon-reload
ifup wlan0
dhcpcd wlan0
```